# How to recover a system font manually from the VGA controller memory?

Tags: assembly, fonts, dos, vga

I have access to an *old* Toshiba 386 PC (T2000Sx) with an extremely **unusual VGA system font**; which I would like to **recover as a font file** and document in a web site.

**How can I write a program which reads the font data from VGA memory and writes it to the floppy?**

The system barely boots from floppy, has little memory (1MB base + 9MB extension) and no hard drive. It used to boot Debian 2.1 via a ZIP drive on the parallel port, but that does not seem to work any more.

The question is a combination of:

1. are there (DOS) programs to do this already? (I have not found any yet; but maybe there are?)
2. programming tools: which language/compiler can I use? Obviously this machine won't run any modern OS, so GCC / VS is out of the question. I had some experience 20 years ago with writing .COM executables manually from assembly, but it is rusty; are there any better programming tools nowadays?
3. VGA standard: at which address in the address space can I find the font data, and how many bytes should I read? I have not found this yet in other sources online.

Comment: Maybe a boot / rescue disk with an older Linux distro (e.g., one that still supports 386), in conjunction with the [SVGAlib](http://www.svgalib.org/) library and utilities?

Comment: Please let me know if you have made any progress with this project. I am extremely interested in precisely these types of old fonts.

Comment: Is your Toshiba 386's font the same one listed in the installable font on this site? https://int10h.org/oldschool-pc-fonts/fontlist/#toshiba_dos_lcd

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a MSDOS 6.22 boot floppy, you can boot the floppy, then run debug and create small assembly programs.

INT 6 (offset hex 18) may be a far pointer to the current font table (at least for 0 to 7fh).

Calling INT 10

```
AX = 1130h
BH = pointer specifier
    00h INT 1Fh pointer
    01h INT 43h pointer
    02h ROM 8x14 character font pointer
    03h ROM 8x8 double dot font pointer
    04h ROM 8x8 double dot font (high 128 characters)
    05h ROM alpha alternate (9 by 14) pointer (EGA,VGA)
    06h ROM 8x16 font (MCGA, VGA)
    07h ROM alternate 9x16 font (VGA only) (see #0020)
    11h (UltraVision v2+) 8x20 font (VGA) or 8x19 font (autosync EGA)
    12h (UltraVision v2+) 8x10 font (VGA) or 8x11 font (autosync EGA)
Return: ES:BP = specified pointer
    CX    = bytes/character of on-screen font (not the requested font!)
    DL    = highest character row on screen
```

You could set cs and ds segment registers to the segment of the video card's bios (probably hex C000), then set cx to the number of bytes, use n to set file name, and do a write. This will create a binary file of the bios. There may be utilities to do this for other operating systems. Then you'll have to find the font data from within the video bios image file.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux `setfont` utility allows you to capture the VGA font currently in use (on the screen) to a file.

I'm not sure how long Linux has had this feature; one idea might be to go digging for extremely old Linux bootdisks (Debian/Slackware/Yggdrasil etc) and finding one with this utility on it, or possibly taking a bootdisk apart and copying the `setfont` binary in. Note that Linux has changed so significantly since the late-1.x/2.0/2.2 days that you will need to do all preparatory work entirely from inside VMs.

To do a thorough job you would also need to do some work with `vga=ask` to push the card into 80x43, 80x50 etc so that you can boot at those resolutions and capture those fonts too.

Depending on your experience levels you may find it easier to experiment with assembly language as the other comment suggests. Note that rapid iteration in this area is easier than ever now; QEMU-KVM (and similar) boots DOS et al in roughly less than a second even on very basic hardware.

Comment: I'm not sure if `setfont` is actually going to dump the video card's own font, or if will simply dump the last font Linux loaded in video RAM with `setfont`.

Comment: An excellent point - in order to grab a correct/accurate VGA ROM dump you need to ensure the system/distro/etc hasn't already loaded a font, because if that's what's in memory, that's what will get dumped. Running without a framebuffer may also help here (because fbcon can load a specific font at kernel init, and that may interfere too).